# How to set value from one geometry node to another?

Tags: geometry-nodes

is there a way of getting values from one geometry node to another. I'd like to make City generator and I need to determine manually for all roads different width and then cut them in landscape. Has anybody solution for that?[image]

Comment: Please do not ask questions twice. If a question is unclear, try to complete it with precise details. This way you avoid that others have to make assumptions when answering, you get a more accurate answer and the added value for this platform and other users increases. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Could you please clarify which values you want to transfer from where to where, and what your node setup looks like? It might also be helpful if you share your blend file.

Answer (score 2):

All 3 primitives have unique geo nodes. The one thing they share is a node group - created by pressing ctrl-g on a single or group of nodes. In your case, the node group would contain a single node as shown, hooked to the output. Press tab to enter or exit the node group. Edit the *value* node to whatever global variable to want the roads to share. Did I interpret your problem correctly?

[image]
[image]
[image]